# In jQuery, how do you select current table TR but not any nested table TR?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

So I tried this:

```
input.find(" tr").each(function(){ ... });
```

I also tried this:

```
input.find(" > tr").each(function(){ ... });
```

Both of these does not work.  The first one will select any TR even if it's under a nested table.  The second one will not work if the table have tbody or anything like that.  Any help?

Input is defined as:

```
var input = $(".mySelectionScope");
```

The DOM would look like this:

```
    <div class='mySelectionScope'>
        <div> // Optional
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>  // Select this one
                        <table>
                            <tr>  // Don't select this one
                            ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with this solution it does not matter whether you have a tbody tag in between:

```
$('table').find('tr:first').parent().children()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out tr's under tr's using [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
input.find("tr").not("tr tr")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter it:

```
input.find("tr").filter(function(){return !$(this).closest('tr').length}).each(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about calling first() on the list of trs?

http://api.jquery.com/first/

Comment: I would need all TR in the first table, just not any TR in nested tables.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery children() instead of find()

From the docs:

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.

The optional div also creates some trickiness...

```
var input = $('.mySelectionScope').children('div').length == 0 ?
        $('.mySelectionScope') : 
        $('.mySelectionScope > div'),
    rows = input.children('table').children('tbody').length == 0 ?
        input.children('table').children('tr') :
        input.children('table').children('tbody').children('tr');
```

if tbody is always inserted in all browsers, the second if statement is not necessary, and you can instead use

```
    rows = input.children('table').children('tbody').children('tr');
```

Pretty ugly, but you can't do this with selectors alone.